Using Nextflow getting "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"
I am facing an issue in my workflow with Nextflow and would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve it. The error I am receiving is:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
Context:

Tool: Nextflow
Nextflow Version: 24.04.2 build 5914
Operating System: Linux 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Execution Environment: Local
Runtime: Groovy 4.0.21 on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.22+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu220.04.1
Type of Analysis: whole genome sequencing analysis

ERROR ~ Error executing process › 'NFCORE_ SAREK: PREPARE_ GENOME: TABIX_GERMLINE_RESOURCE (1)
Caused by:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

I have checked .nextflow.log and nextflow.config but still don't know how to solve it. I have tried increasing the timeout but it hasn't worked either.
How can I adjust Nextflow's network settings to avoid timeout errors?
Are there specific configurations within Nextflow that can help manage network timeouts effectively?
What are the recommended practices for configuring network settings in Nextflow pipelines?
Your insights and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your assistance.
